# SQL REPLICATE() function not replicating and simply returning a single instance of the provided string when assigning to variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, while-loop, replicate

I'm currently trying to solve an SQL programming challenge (building a triangular structure using asterisk characters). Example output below (3 rows);

```
* * * 
* *
*
```

I have written code which I believe should work (coming from some hobby C# experience, so I may be approaching this in the completely wrong way). However, my use of the `REPLICATE()` function appears to only output the provided character/string once, without actually replicating.

I have provided my current code here:

```
DECLARE @n INT = 3;
DECLARE @output NVARCHAR;
DECLARE @nextLine NVARCHAR;
DECLARE @char NVARCHAR = '* ';

WHILE @n > 0
BEGIN
    SET @nextLine = REPLICATE(@char, @n);
    SET @output = CONCAT(@output, @nextLine, CHAR(10));
    SET @n = @n - 1;
END

PRINT TRIM(@output);
```

Expected output:

```
* * * 
* *
*
```

Actual current output:

```
*
```

To clarify/re-iterate in a different way;

```
SELECT REPLICATE(@char, @n);
SET @output = REPLICATE(@char, @n);
SELECT @output;
```

The 1st SELECT above, returns the expected output (a string like '* * * * *....'), however, the 2nd SELECT - trying to SET that as a variable's value, only retains a single asterisk ('*'). Why?

Comment: Declaring `[N]VARCHAR` fields without a length is a [bad habit to kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length), and explains your seemingly "wrong" results.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert that solved it. Very interesting article too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare Length of the parameter `@output` and `@nextLine`.

```
DECLARE @output NVARCHAR(50);
DECLARE @nextLine NVARCHAR(50);
```

Comment: Thanks @ch2019, that was the issue! :(